# Unity Networking Manager with 2 different applications

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

im trying to build a simple 2-Player game for a education project (In the game each player has to collect rings). 
I should say, that im new into Unity so that's my first project with it.

The main problem right now is the set up for the game. It should be played on 1 display but the input for the second player position has to come from a second pc. This is because we using a kind of MIDI controllers and we can't connect both on one pc.

Input Player 2 (PC2/Client) -> Input Player 1 & whole game logic (PC1/Server/Host) -> Display (of PC1)

I hope you understand what i mean.

My plan was to put the whole game logic and the input of the first player in the first program and get only the position of the second player of a second program with a different code.

I tried a Networking Tutorial and that worked, but it was the same code for both players.

Im using the Network Manager but don't use the spawn function from it. I spawn the the player objects later.
Im using the Network Manager in both programs and i get a connection from the client to the host. The problem is i don't get the variable from the client into the host.

Code of the first program:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class managementGame : NetworkBehaviour {

public int StreamMessage;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}

void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Debug.Log (StreamMessage);
}
}
```

Code of the second program:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Controlls : NetworkBehaviour    {

public int message;
public int StreamMessage;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Return)) {
        message = 1;
        CmdMsg(message);
    }
}
[Command]
public void CmdMsg(int Message) {
    StreamMessage = Message;    
}
}
```

As far as i know that code should work or is there somewhere a mistake?

I'm also getting some information from the second program, maybe someone knows what they mean:
Network configuration mismatch detected. The number of networked scripts on the client does not match the number of networked scripts on the server. This could be caused by lazy loading of scripts on the client. This warning can be disabled by the checkbox in NetworkManager Script CRC Check. UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()

And also this:

CRC Local Dump Controlls : 0
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()

If there isn't a solution I would try to spawn the player objects with the Network Manager and rewrite the code.

And sorry for the many english mistakes!

edit: The main question: Is it possible to connect 2 Unity application with different scripts with the Network Manager? And send variables with [Command]?

Comment: Very detailed post, however I feel you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You might have made a mistake in going the networking route. Look back to your original problem, 2 midi controllers on one PC. Surely it's easier to solve that issue with a cheap external midi interface or something than to create a networking project on your first ever time with Unity? Seems like you might have over thought this one. If you are worried about the 2 controllers sending the same midi notes, then have the controllers use different channels, or even make them send different notes perhaps? Sorry for no positive info but i really think you should take a step back and rethink this.

Comment: @Hristo : the question was if the code (as i wrote) should work. I read something about that 2 different applications can't connect through the Network Manager.

Comment: @turnipinrut : We using 2 Palette Gears as the controller for the game. As the developer mentioned we can't connect 2 Palette Gears core (the connection between the Gears and the pc) to the same pc.

Comment: @SeGa so you never tested the code you have provided?

Comment: @Hristo As i wrote in the long post, i tested it but it didn't worked. I also wrote the logs I'm getting from the second application.